# MDX and PeriodsToDate

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm very new to MDX so I hope this is a simple question for a MDX expert.  I have the following expression SUM(PeriodsToDate([Accounting Date].[(All)]),[Measures].[Amount]) which this piece works as expected.  I need to add a filter or IIF statement that basically does the following:

```
IF 
  SUM(PeriodsToDate([Accounting Date].[(All)]),[Measures].[Amount]) < 0 
    Then 0
Else 
  SUM(PeriodsToDate([Accounting Date].[(All)]),[Measures].[Amount])
```

Comment: It's not clear at what stage you want the IIF to operate.  Exclude all individual values of the measure which are <0 from the SUM?  Aggregate the measure (e.g. per-member of some other dimension) and the transform the <0 values to 0?  Or aggregate the measure, giving a single value, and then apply the "replace <0 with 0".  With more detail on this it'll be much easier to suggest a solution.  Also, is this expression used to define a cube calculated measure, or a query-level calculated measure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's impossible to do with pre-aggregated data. The MDX IIF function works per a member, the SQL IIF works per a row. You have to add a measure like Amount, but with iif([Amount] < 0,0,[Amount]). Also you may try the code below, nonetheless, I doubt it results properly:

```
SUM(
    NULL:[Accounting Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,
    IIF(
        [Measures].[Amount] < 0,
        NULL,
        [Measures].[Amount] 
    )
)
```