# Analysis Services - calculated member - count by dimension key range

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, analysis

Hello I´m struggling with MS SSAS...
simplified I have two tables in my Data-view.
T1 holds a PK and a Date.
T2 holds a PK, a FK of T1, and some numbers.

I created an dimension from T1 with its two attributes.
So I can created a Cube to aggregate the Data of T2 by date and id of T1.
So far so good.

What I want to do next is the aggregation of just a part of that data.
Example:
"Show me the aggregated data of T2 records that have a FK >=970"

So I tried to write a calculated measure, but failed. I searched around the web but I found nothing worked so far...

I hope someone can help with a hint.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167709/mdx-and-periodstodate/42168904 
Do you want to filter a record or a member with FK >=970?

Comment: I want to aggregate all t2 record that are related to records of t1 with t1.id >=970. I sql it would be something like: SELECT SUM([SomeData]) FROM [T2] WHERE [T2].[FK] IN (SELECT [ID] FROM [T1] WHERE [ID] >= 970)

Comment: There is no way to do that in MDX, except adding the [ID] column as a dimension attribute and filter within Where clause. Otherwise you should add a new measure where you filter out these records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly, your date Dimension is T1.

In your dimension you should have a dimension Key setup, i'll assume you did it at the PK column. Within the properties you can define 3 things for that attribute.
KeyColumns
NameColumns
ValueColumns

Make sure your KeyColumns is the PK Column. And should be a OrderBy property you should make sure is set to "Key"

After that if your PKs are sequencial(they really should!) you can make a MDX query like this:

```
SELECT
{ [Measures].[YOURMEASURE] } ON COLUMNS,
{ [T1].&[970] : NULL } ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

EDIT:
Sure. Add to your Calculation in the Cube.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[MyOver970Measure]
AS
AGGREGATE({ [T1].&[970] : NULL },[Measures].[YOURMEASURE])
,VISIBLE=1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a measure of that?